# Yahoo Calendar - What does TAS mean?

Tags: yahoofinance, earnings

I'm trying to make sense of values reported on Yahoo Finance Calendar [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings)

There's a value for 'Earnings Call Time' that reads TAS. Does anybody know what that means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It stands for Transfer Agent System.  This type of earnings announcement is not announced via a press release.  The transfer agent directly communicates the earnings to all shareholders of record.

Answer (score -1):

No. It means Trading At Settlement. Meaning orders on futures can be accepted on the settlement date.

Comment: In the context of "Earnings Call Time"? No, I don't think so. Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/66289/