# What does it means in earning " TNS"

Tags: earnings

I'm trying to make sense of values reported on Yahoo Finance Calendar here

There's a value for 'Earnings Call Time' that reads TNS. Does anybody know what that means?

Answer (score 3):

TNS means "time not specified".

Other abbreviations you might see in this context:

DNS "date not specified"

BMO "before market open"

AMC "after market close"

TAS "Transfer Agent System"